# Getting AttributeError while training DNN classifer

Tags: string, tensorflow, classification, attributeerror

Here is the code:

```
continous=['age', 'education_num', 'capital_gain', 'capital_loss', 'hours_per_week']
```

**creating feat_cols**

I have automated the process using for loop

```
feat_cols = []

for col in census.columns:
    ## Continous - Unchanged
    if col in continous:
        feat_cols.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(col))

    ## Categorical - Trick, no need to count
    elif col!='income_bracket':
        print('Embedded {}'.format(col))
     feat_cols.append(tf.feature_column.embedding_column(categorical_column=col,dimension=X_train[col].nunique()))
```

**Creating model**
Importing Tensorflow I've created this model.

```
dnnmodel = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[7,7,7], feature_columns=feat_cols, n_classes=2)

ip_dnn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(X_train, y_train, num_epochs=None,shuffle=True)


dnnmodel.train(input_fn=ip_dnn, steps=5000)
```

**Error:**

Earlier with LinearClassifier everything worked fine.

```
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-751f0a94d0d2> in <module>()
      1 # ip_func created earliar
      2 
----> 3 dnnmodel.train(input_fn=ip_dnn, steps=5000)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
    356 
    357       saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
--> 358       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    359       logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    360       return self

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1122       return self._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1123     else:
-> 1124       return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1125 
   1126   def _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1152       worker_hooks.extend(input_hooks)
   1153       estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(
-> 1154           features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
   1155       global_step_tensor = training_util.get_global_step(g)
   1156       return self._train_with_estimator_spec(estimator_spec, worker_hooks,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, config)
   1110 
   1111     logging.info('Calling model_fn.')
-> 1112     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
   1113     logging.info('Done calling model_fn.')
   1114 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py in _model_fn(features, labels, mode, config)
    520           input_layer_partitioner=input_layer_partitioner,
    521           config=config,
--> 522           batch_norm=batch_norm)
    523 
    524     super(DNNClassifier, self).__init__(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py in _dnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode, head, hidden_units, feature_columns, optimizer, activation_fn, dropout, input_layer_partitioner, config, use_tpu, batch_norm)
    285         input_layer_partitioner=input_layer_partitioner,
    286         batch_norm=batch_norm)
--> 287     logits = logit_fn(features=features, mode=mode)
    288 
    289     if use_tpu:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py in dnn_logit_fn(features, mode)
    101         batch_norm,
    102         name='dnn')
--> 103     return dnn_model(features, mode)
    104 
    105   return dnn_logit_fn

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    552             # In graph mode, failure to build the layer's graph
    553             # implies a user-side bug. We don't catch exceptions.
--> 554             outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    555           else:
    556             try:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py in call(self, features, mode)
    193           'input_from_feature_columns',
    194           partitioner=self._input_layer_partitioner):
--> 195         net = self._input_layer(features)
    196       for i in range(len(self._hidden_layers)):
    197         net = self._hidden_layers[i](net)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py in __call__(self, features)
    335         trainable=self._trainable,
    336         cols_to_vars=None,
--> 337         from_template=True)
    338 
    339   @property

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\template.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    366           custom_getter=self._custom_getter) as vs:
    367         self._variable_scope = vs
--> 368         return self._call_func(args, kwargs)
    369 
    370   @property

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\template.py in _call_func(self, args, kwargs)
    309         # Checkpointable).
    310         with checkpointable_util.capture_dependencies(template=self):
--> 311           result = self._func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313       if self._variables_created:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py in _internal_input_layer(features, feature_columns, weight_collections, trainable, cols_to_vars, scope, cols_to_output_tensors, from_template)
    179   """See input_layer. `scope` is a name or variable scope to use."""
    180 
--> 181   feature_columns = _normalize_feature_columns(feature_columns)
    182   for column in feature_columns:
    183     if not isinstance(column, _DenseColumn):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py in _normalize_feature_columns(feature_columns)
   2266   name_to_column = dict()
   2267   for column in feature_columns:
-> 2268     if column.name in name_to_column:
   2269       raise ValueError('Duplicate feature column name found for columns: {} '
   2270                        'and {}. This usually means that these columns refer to '

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column_v2.py in name(self)
   2960   def name(self):
   2961     """See `FeatureColumn` base class."""
-> 2962     return '{}_embedding'.format(self.categorical_column.name)
   2963 
   2964   @property

**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'**

originally defined at:
  File "C:\Users\Subham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py", line 102, in dnn_logit_fn
    name='dnn')
  File "C:\Users\Subham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py", line 134, in __init__
    create_scope_now=False)
  File "C:\Users\Subham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py", line 327, in __init__
    self._name, _internal_input_layer, create_scope_now_=create_scope_now)
  File "C:\Users\Subham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\template.py", line 154, in make_template
    **kwargs)
```

Comment: Why would you add "Lorem ipsum..." underneath a question? :D

Comment: They were prompting me to write more...xD